# Using File.SetCreationTime and File.SetLastWriteTime makes Windows Explorer hide these details for the file

Tags: c#, windows, file, datetime, explorer

I encountered something weird while trying to set CreationTime and LastWriteTime on a file.

```
DateTime nDT = new DateTime(1974, 12, 23,10,31,34);
string path = @"C:\Users\matte\Desktop\Desktop_Test.zip";
File.SetCreationTime(path, nDT);
File.SetLastWriteTime(path, nDT);
```

I'm using this code in a console app and when it runs, it updates those properties but the related values disappear from Windows Explorer.

[image: File with new CreatonTime and LastWriteTime]

Did I make any mistake?

Comment: If you open the file's properties you should see those dates shown as expected. Perhaps those dates being before the birth of Windows has something to do with why the file explorer is not showing it in the list

Comment: 1/1/1980 is a sentinel value, but it's supposed to be that exact date only. I recall running into this problem with that specific date (and some prior), in fact I believe with exceptions thrown when using the exact date. Anyways https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20161108-00/?p=94665 but obviously your value is before then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will not see it if date is before 1980, 1, 1. There are too many articles but the one makes sense to me is https://superuser.com/questions/796762/what-is-the-range-of-dates-that-windows-explorer-can-display.